# How to wipe links in plain table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

In Python 3 I need to extract the links that are in a table in a site. I did so

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

geral = urlopen("http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/dados-abertos-do-cnpj")

bsObje =  BeautifulSoup(geral, "lxml")

estados = bsObje.findAll("table", {"class":"plain"})

print(estados)
```

Output:

```
[<table class="plain"><tbody><tr><th><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214AC" target="_self" title="Acre">Acre</a></th><th><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214ES" target="_self" title="">Espírito Santo</a></th><th><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214PB" target="_self" title="Paraíba">Paraíba</a></th><th><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214RO" target="_self" title="Rondônia">Rondônia</a></th></tr><tr><td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214AL" target="_self" title="Alagos">Alagoas</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214GO" target="_self" title="Goiás">Goiás</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214PR" target="_self" title="Paraná">Paraná</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214RR" target="_self" title="Roraima">Roraima</a></strong></td>
</tr><tr><td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214AP" target="_self" title="Amapá">Amapá</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214MA" target="_self" title="Maranhão">Maranhão</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214PE" target="_self" title="Pernambuco">Pernambuco</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214SC" target="_self" title="Santa Catarina">Santa Catarina</a></strong></td>
</tr><tr><td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214AM" target="_self" title="Amazonas">Amazonas</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214MT" target="_self" title="Mato Grosso">Mato Grosso</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214PI" target="_self" title="Piauí">Piauí</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214SP" target="_self" title="São Paulo">São Paulo</a></strong></td>
</tr><tr><td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214BA" target="_self" title="Bahia">Bahia</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214MS" target="_self" title="Mato Grosso do Sul">Mato Grosso do Sul</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214RJ" target="_self" title="Rio de Janeiro">Rio de Janeiro</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214SE" target="_self" title="Sergipe">Sergipe</a></strong></td>
</tr><tr><td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214CE" target="_self" title="Ceará">Ceará</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214MG" target="_self" title="Minas Gerais">Minas Gerais</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214RN" target="_self" title="Rio Grande do Norte">Rio Grande do Norte</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214TO" target="_self" title="Tocantins">Tocantins</a></strong></td>
</tr><tr><td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214DF" target="_self" title="Distrito Federal">Distrito Federal</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214PA" target="_self" title="Pará">Pará</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a class="external-link" href="http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214RS" target="_self" title="Rio Grande do Sul">Rio Grande do Sul</a></strong></td>
<td></td>
</tr></tbody></table>]
```

I want to extract "href" and "title" to create a list or dictionary.

I tried to iterate in `estados` but it generated an empty value:

```
for name in estados:
    url = name.get('href')
    local = name.get('title')
    print(local)
    print(url)
```

Output:

```
None
None
```

Please, in this case how could I extract the 'href' and its respective title from each table item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I could understand you properly then the below code will get you there:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

dict_val={}

res = requests.get("http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/dados-abertos-do-cnpj")
soup =  BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
table = soup.select("table.plain")[0]
for items in table.select("tr"):
    data = [[item.text,item['href']] for item in items.select(".external-link")]
    for data_dict in data:
        dict_val[data_dict[0]] = data_dict[1]

print(dict_val)
```

Partial output:

```
{'Alagoas': 'http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214AL', 'Pará': 'http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214PA',
```

Comment: Thank you all. Specifically in this response the title value for "Espírito Santo" came empty. This should be code error on the site, right? One way to avoid this would be to just scratch the text?

Comment: Updated the code. Check it now. No empty value is there. Don't get confused to see `Alagoas` in the first position, all the values you can grab now.

Answer (score 3):

You are iterating over a list with a single element. Try this:

```
for name in estados[0].findAll("a"):
   url = name.get('href')
   local = name.get('title')
   print(local)
   print(url)
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) it appears that you should change `for name in estados` to:

```
for name in estados.find_all('a'):
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps fetching all `<a>` tags with the class `external-link` in your table helps.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

geral = urlopen("http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria    /cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/dados-abertos-do-cnpj")

bsObje =  BeautifulSoup(geral, "lxml")

estados = bsObje.findAll("table", {"class":"plain"})[0].findAll('a', {"class":"external-link"})

estados = {a.get('title'): a.get('href') for a in estados}
print(estados)
```

You may also get rid of that index if you are only interested in the first (maybe only) table by using `find` instead of `findAll`:

```
estados = bsObje.find("table", {"class":"plain"}).findAll('a', {"class":"external-link"})
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the fact that OP's code lists  only links in the *table* element.

Comment: That is correct, thanks for the heads up. I just changed my answer in an attempt to account for that.